# Erlang websocket client with cowboy server

Tags: websocket, erlang

Im trying to use this websocket client library but with little success. 
[Erlang websocket client](https://github.com/jeremyong/websocket_client)

If someone used this library to build a client talking to a remote server, how were you able to send messages ?

The basic usage shows to call this to inititate a connection,

```
websocket_client:start_link("wss://echo.websocket.org", ?MODULE, []).
```

and  cast/2 to send a message to a remote server.

```
websocket_client:cast(self(), {text, <<"message 1">>}).
```

However, if I try to use the same function else where in the code to send a text/binary frame to remote server, its not helping.

Is there anything that Im missing ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that the first parameter to `websocket_client:cast/2` must be the pid for the `websocket_client` process. You can get the pid from the `start_link` call, e.g.:

```
{ok, Pid} = websocket_client:start_link("wss://echo.websocket.org", ?MODULE, []).
```

And to cast a message to the remote server:

```
websocket_client:cast(Pid, {text, <<"message 1">>}).
```

In the example code for the `websocket_client` project `cast` is called from within the `init` function, in this case they can use `self()` since the `init` function is actually executed by the websocket client process.

Similarly if you are calling `cast` from within your `websocket_handle`/`websocket_info` callback functions you can use `self()` since those are also called by the websocket client process.